# Uploading video in server from ios showing 0bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c

Video is uploading but showing 0bytes when I checked web data its showing nil on web data.

```
 NSString *str1=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.mp4"];
    NSLog(@"str1=%@",str1);

    NSString *escapedUrlString = [str1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"escapedUrlString=%@",escapedUrlString);

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
    NSLog(@"videoURL=%@",videoURL);

    NSData *newdata = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfFile:escapedUrlString];
    webdata=[NSData dataWithData:newdata];
    NSLog(@"webData = %@",webdata);

    NSData *videoData = webdata;
    NSString *urlString = @"http://192.168.1.92/Abdul/IOS/Chat/upload/upload_vid.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\".mp4\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"returnString=== %@", returnString);

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    webdata1 =[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [webdata1 appendData:data];

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:webdata1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

<?php

    "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
     "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";


      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get path like,

```
  NSString *str1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"mp4"];
```

then get `videoData` like,

```
  NSData *videoData = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfFile:str1];
```

then pass this `videoData` directly to `request body` like,

```
  [body appendData:videoData];
```

Remove extra code and replace this lines which i wrote with existing. your problem may solve.

**Update :**

```
  NSString *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"mp4"];
  NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoURL]];
```

pass this video data to request body and first check that you are getting data to `videoData`.

And secoond thing you should use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to send data. it is make it more simpler.

example by afnetworking

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"you url"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/videoupload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
                            {
                                [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"myVideo.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
                            }];


  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];

   [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {

 NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

}];

[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {NSLog(@"Video Uploaded Successfully");}
                              failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {NSLog(@"Error : %@",  operation.responseString);}];


 [operation start];
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: No I am getting nill only for str1 for demo.mp4

Comment: NSString *str1=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.mp4"];  use this line and pass it to datawithcontentoffile

Comment: according to your old code will you get data in `newData` ?

Comment: I have added str1 to data with content of file but it is nill only

Comment: in my old code after this three line data is nill     NSString *str1=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.mp4"];
  
    NSString *escapedUrlString = [str1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding  
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];

Comment: check my update in answer. try to get data like this. first two line of code in my updated answer. then check if you get data then set it in request body with your existing code. if you get data by this and unable to send to server then use afnetwoorking as suggested in answer. and make sure that your video file name is demo.mp4 and it is in main bundle

Comment: For this line getting nill NSString *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"mp4"];

Comment: for this line getting url : NSString *str1=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"demo.mp4"];            /Users/vysimac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E9EB9D27-BA59-49D2-AF9E-557E1758625E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/530F78DB-2728-4D84-9FC9-8C7BC54EF361/helo.app/demo.mp4

Comment: important thing is to get data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109997/discussion-between-abdulheru-and-lion).

Comment: @Raja you should have design you api like that it will accepts `credentials` as parameter along with your data!